How to Return only interface members in JSON result from ASP.NET Core Web API
I have a simple API which returns a list of rows from the database like this:
[HttpGet]
[Route("list/{count}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<IResult>>> GetRows(int count)
{
    var list = await dbc.GetList(count);
    return new JsonResult( list.ToList<IResult>() );
}

The database returns a row with attributes id, name, status etc. whereas the interface has a subset like this:
public class Result
{
   int id { get; set; }
   string name { get; set; }
   int status { get; set; }
}

public interface IResult
{
   int id { get; set; }
   string name { get; set; }
}

I have the .ToList() to return only the fields in the json result, is there a better/more efficient way than to convert to another List() first ?

does list.Cast<IResult>() work?

@DStanley JsonConvert and STJ use the actual runtime "concrete" type of objects as their serialization contract by default - casting a reference-type to an implemented interface-type doesn't change object identity nor its actual runtime type - you could even also cast them all to System.Object and get the same result.

@Dai I presumed that as well, but list.ToList<IResult>() apparently works despite not changing the actual object type.

@DStanley That is probably because you've got STJ using source-generators for JSON serialization instead of using runtime reflection. Source-generators will use the static type (which is an interface-type in this instance) - so I expect you'd see the same effect if you cast to a supertype like System.Object (so you'd get a JSON array of empty JSON object-literals, as System.Object doesn't have any public instance properties).

BTW, regarding interface IResult - I advocate making those member-properties get-only.

@Dai list.Cast() does not work, it shows status as well, the IResult was generated by extract interface with get;set;, will cleanup, thanks
